# Python pandas not saving csv file in correct format and increasing size of file(observed that integer values are saved as decimal in csv[250 =250.0])

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, selenium-webdriver

Python pandas is not saving csv file in correct format and increasing size of the file. Observed that integer values are saved as decimal in the csv file e.g. 250 value is saved 250.0 from python code.

**Note:** I am not updating 250 integer value. I am updating other columns. But looks like from python its saving as default to decimal

I am using python pandas library. I have one task where I have to read the existing csv file and update some columns in that csv with new values and upload that file on UI on the web application

It is not writing the exact same thing in a CSV file using Python pandas. Original size 36k and after update size is 37k

**Failing**: The file updated by my python code is working fine and also updating values in the CSV file but it's showing file size is 37k.
When I upload the same 37k file on UI, it is failing.

**Passing:** When I manually open the above-updated file by python code in excel and just save it without changing anything then the size of the file is 36k and that file is working and I am able to upload on UI successfully

- pandas==1.3.1
- Python 3.8.3

Steps I am doing:

1. Read csv using below code with file size 36k
2. Update some columns using python code (Here I observed it is saving  integer values as decimal in the csv file e.g. 250.0)
3. Check file size which is now 37k after update
4. Just open the same file which is 37k I. E updated by code in excel format
5. Just save without changing any content (Here I observed it is saving integer as decimal in the csv file e.g. 250)
6. Now check file size becomes 36k which uploads successfully

Below code is updating file as expected:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
# updating the column value/data
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    df.loc[i,'Your_Name']= random_name
    df.loc[i,'Pay_Number'] = random_number
df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
```

Why it's changing the size of the file when I save it through python code and working when just open the same file in excel and save it without changing anything?

When I am saving the from python code , file size is 37k and when I just opened same file in excel updated by python code and just click save without updating any content. Then size of same file is 36k . So that is the difference when saving from code , something is added extra

Note:

I tried to close the file, rename, replace, move the file after updating then upload on UI but no luck.

Comment: The change of size is not dramatic and can be expected. Your updates may have made the file longer. Or it could be caused by different but equivalent quoting, for example. Pick out a sample line that differs in the input and output, and tell us why you think it is wrong, or at least what your failing upload says is wrong. The filesize is most unlikely to be the reason why the file is being rejected.

Comment: @BoarGules , See, when I am saving from python code , file size is 37k and when I just opened same file in excel updated by python code and just click save without updating any content. Then size of same file is 36k . So that is the difference when saving from code , something is added extra

Comment: Check my updated steps and please let me know how size is changing in above case?

Comment: Python pandas is not saving csv file in correct format and increasing size of the file(observed that integer values are saved as decimal in the csv file e.g. 250 is saved as 250.0 when update from python code. And when we just open the same file updated by python code and save it then it keeps the same format

Comment: Why are you just talking about file size and not about the actual differences in the file? Is it just ".0" in your numbers?

Comment: `pandas` is clearly treating the input values as `float`s. If you need that degree of control over the format of the output file, then consider doing your updates using the much simpler and more basic `csv` module. An alternative might be to change the datatype of the dataframe columns to integer using `astype`.

Comment: Do you have that link, how to update the csv instead of pandas? How to update columns values using basic csv modules

Comment: I find the standard documentation quite adequate: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html . `csv.reader` gives you one `list` per line, you change the list elements if necessary, then use `csv.writer` to write them out again.

Comment: Please could use open the two CSV files into notepad (not Excel) and copy/paste the first few rows from each into your question (as is). We could then understand what the problem actually is.

Comment: I have compared both the files and observed python pandas is changing integer values to floating values eg. 250 is written as 250.0 by pandas

Comment: You would need to tell pandas the required type of those columns. Seeing example rows (and header) would have helped.